# IP camera streaming(rtsp) error on Android studio

Tags: android, camera, rtsp-client

I try to get an IP camera view on wifi camera board, directly, using nexus s phone.
Using VideoView, I can get the video on the Internet, http and rtsp address, but I can't get the camera image on the board(rtsp board) through direct wifi connection.

below is the simple and short code, easy to understand, and error msg.
plz, help me. thanks

```
String vidAddress = "rtsp://192.168.100.1/cam1/h264/";
VideoView vidView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    vidView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
    Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
    vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
    vidView.requestFocus();
    vidView.start();
}

03-16 19:07:26.091  27449-27449/com.example.administrator.rtspapplication D/MediaPlayer﹕ Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
03-16 19:07:26.450  27449-27453/com.example.administrator.rtspapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 176K, 3% free 8340K/8583K, paused 143ms+3ms, total 182ms
03-16 19:07:26.450  27449-27449/com.example.administrator.rtspapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 6ms
03-16 19:07:26.524  27449-27449/com.example.administrator.rtspapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-16 19:07:27.110  27449-27449/com.example.administrator.rtspapplication D/MediaPlayer﹕ getMetadata
03-16 19:07:28.309  27449-27461/com.example.administrator.rtspapplication W/IMediaDeathNotifier﹕ media server died
03-16 19:07:28.309  27449-27461/com.example.administrator.rtspapplication E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (100, 0)
03-16 19:07:28.317  27449-27460/com.example.administrator.rtspapplication W/AudioSystem﹕ AudioFlinger server died!
03-16 19:07:28.434  27449-27449/com.example.administrator.rtspapplication E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (100,0)
03-16 19:07:28.434  27449-27449/com.example.administrator.rtspapplication D/VideoView﹕ Error: 100,0
```

Comment: What do you mean by direct wifi? Does that mean Wi-Fi direct?

Comment: You're trying to stream a video, meaning that you're getting video data from the network. Network operations on the main UI thread are forbidden. (I'm surprised this didn't crash your application.) Create a separate thread, and try  to perform the operation there.

Comment: I'm a beginer in Android. Anyway, above code can work well, when I get the video source on the Internet. But my situation is that I have a board that makes rtsp server - camera stream - and make a wifi connection, so I can get a camera stream through VLC player using above URL.(directly connect board and phone) But I can not get the camera stream using my code(short and simple code).